# Не работает задержка millis() esp8266

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

У меня есть:

1. esp8266
2. Матрица MAX7219
3. Библа GyverMAX7219.h

Так же есть функция вывода времени и температуры с интернета(что-то типа умных часов) и в функции вывода температуры должна быть задержка, delay() на удивление работает нормально, но его использовать нельзя. Остаётся только millis(), но в условной конструкции, такое ощущение, что таймер не срабатывает, а в конструкции цикла while,таймер срабатывает, температуру выводит, но по искончанию esp8266 ресетается. Подобное встречал раньше когда хотел сделать мигающее двоеточие, но там двоеточие по времени таймера сначала нету (так и должно быть), мигает и моментально пропадает. Я думаю, что тут один общий косяк. Помогите пожалуйста!
p.s Если нужен весь код, скажите, предоставлю.

```
#define INTERNET_WEATHER_TIME 10000
void outInfo(bool time, bool tempInternet)
{
  if(time)
  {
    internetTime();
  }
  if (tempInternet)
  {
    const unsigned long interval = INTERNET_WEATHER_TIME;
    static unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)
    {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      internetTemperature();
      //тут всё ок
    }
  }
  
}

void internetTime()
{
  matrix.clear();
  matrix.setCursor(3, 1);
  matrix.print(String(hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);
  matrix.setCursor(14, 1);
  matrix.print(":");
  matrix.setCursor(18, 1);
  matrix.print(String(minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes);
  matrix.update();
}

void internetTemperature()
{

  matrix.clear();
  matrix.setCursor(10, 1);
  matrix.print(temperature);
  matrix.setCursor(16, 1);
  matrix.print("C");
  matrix.update();
  const unsigned long interval = 5000;
  static unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)
  {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    //тут проблема
  }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте  в вопрос, как вы объявляете `currentMillis, previousMillis, interval` и какое значение для интервала у вас указано?

Comment: не совсем понимаю, то подразумевается по "объявляете", они же уже инициализированы. И я сделал комментарий где не работает таймер.

Comment: Написал комментарий, а потом убрал, т.к. у вас тут `static` и одинаковые имена переменных - эту кашу надо переделывать по-хорошему. Как минимум - разные имена переменным `currentMillis` дайте.

Comment: Так они же в разных полях видимости. Или это не так работает? Но я попробую - отпишусь (Если, что я С++ изучаю только около полу года, и по этому могу ошибаться)

Comment: Да я вот с С++ тоже не сильно знаком, но вот это вот явно сбивающие с толку места, где лучше делать "попроще".

Comment: Ну я по пробывал, как я и предпологал ничего не изменилось. Покопался в коде и если отключить отображение часов, а они отображались на постоянке, то есть time = false, то отображается все нормально. Такое ощущение что происходит какое-то наложение что-ли часов и температуры